# Подергивания в CSS анимации

Tags: css, css3

Почему анимация дергается (вверх поднимается рывками)?

```css
header.paralax {
    height: 520px;
}

header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
@-webkit-keyframes sky_background {
 0% {
  background: url(http://extremje.beget.tech/assets/img/index/top.png););
  color: #007fd5
 }
 100% {
  background: url(http://extremje.beget.tech/assets/img/index/top.png););
  color: #007fd5
 }
}
.sky {
    height: 100%;   
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-animation: sky_background 50s ease-out infinite;
    -moz-animation: sky_background 50s ease-out infinite;
    -o-animation: sky_background 50s ease-out infinite;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.moon {
 background: url("http://extremje.beget.tech/assets/img/oblako/cloud_one.png");
 position: absolute;
 background-size: 7%;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 height: 1000%;
 width: 100%;
 -webkit-animation: moon 70s infinite cubic-bezier(0.45, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
 -moz-animation: moon 70s infinite cubic-bezier(0.45, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
 -o-animation: moon 70s infinite cubic-bezier(0.45, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);

    animation-direction: normal;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.25,0.1,0.25,1)
}

.clouds_one {
 background: url("http://extremje.beget.tech/assets/img/oblako/cloud_one.png");
 position: absolute;
 background-size: 8%;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 300%;
 -webkit-animation: cloud_one 70s infinite cubic-bezier(0.45, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
 -moz-animation: cloud_one 70s infinite cubic-bezier(0.45, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
 -o-animation: cloud_one 70s infinite cubic-bezier(0.45, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    animation-direction: normal;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.25,0.1,0.25,1)
}

.clouds_two {
 background: url("http://extremje.beget.tech/assets/img/oblako/cloud_two.png");
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 background-size: 12%;
 top: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 300%;
 -webkit-animation: cloud_two 75s infinite cubic-bezier(0.45, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
 -moz-animation: cloud_two 75s infinite cubic-bezier(0.45, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
 -o-animation: cloud_two 75s infinite cubic-bezier(0.45, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    animation-direction: normal;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.25,0.1,0.25,1)
}

.clouds_three {
 background: url("http://extremje.beget.tech/assets/img/oblako/cloud_three.png");
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 background-size: 9%;
 top: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 300%;

 -webkit-animation: cloud_three 100s infinite cubic-bezier(0.45, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
 -moz-animation: cloud_three 100s infinite cubic-bezier(0.45, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
 -o-animation: cloud_three 100s infinite cubic-bezier(0.45, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95);
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    animation-direction: normal;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.25,0.1,0.25,1)
}


@-webkit-keyframes moon {
0% {
    top: 50%;
}
100% {
    top: -100%;
}

}
@-webkit-keyframes cloud_one {
0% {
    top: 50%;
}
100% {
    top: -100%;
}
}

@-webkit-keyframes cloud_two {
  0% {
    top: 50%;
}
100% {
    top: -100%;
}
}

@-webkit-keyframes cloud_three {
 0% {
    top: 50%;
}
100% {
    top: -100%;
}
}
```

```html
  <header class="paralax">
  <div class="sky" style="http://extremje.beget.tech/assets/img/index/top.png);">
      <div class="moon"></div>
      <div class="clouds_one"></div>
      <div class="clouds_two"></div>
      <div class="clouds_three"></div>
  </div>
 
</header>
```

---

получилось, а как зациклить такую анимацию и уменьшить скорость?

```css
header.paralax {
    height: 520px;
    transform: translateZ(0);
}

header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
@-webkit-keyframes sky_background {
 0% {
  background: url(http://extremje.beget.tech/assets/img/index/top.png););
  color: #007fd5
 }
 100% {
  background: url(http://extremje.beget.tech/assets/img/index/top.png););
  color: #007fd5
 }
}
.sky {
    height: 100%;   
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-animation: sky_background 350s ease-out infinite;
    -moz-animation: sky_background 350s ease-out infinite;
    -o-animation: sky_background 350s ease-out infinite;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
}

.moon {
 background: url("http://extremje.beget.tech/assets/img/oblako/cloud_one.png");
 position: absolute;
 background-size: 65%;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 height: 1000%;
 width: 100%;
-webkit-animation: cloud_three 1600s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: cloud_three 1600s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: cloud_three 1600s linear infinite;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);

}

.clouds_one {
 background: url("http://extremje.beget.tech/assets/img/oblako/cloud_one.png");
 position: absolute;
 background-size:54%;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 300%;
-webkit-animation: cloud_three 300s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: cloud_three 300s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: cloud_three 300s linear infinite;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.clouds_two {
 background: url("http://extremje.beget.tech/assets/img/oblako/cloud_two.png");
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 background-size: 40%;
 top: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 300%;
-webkit-animation: cloud_three 300s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: cloud_three 300s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: cloud_three 300s linear infinite;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.clouds_three {
 background: url("http://extremje.beget.tech/assets/img/oblako/cloud_three.png");
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 background-size: 76%;
 top: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 300%;

-webkit-animation: cloud_three 300s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: cloud_three 300s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: cloud_three 300s linear infinite;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    animation-direction: normal;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.25,0.1,0.25,1)
}

@-webkit-keyframes sky_background {
 0% {
  background: url(http://extremje.beget.tech/assets/img/index/top.png);
  color: #007fd5
 }
 100% {
  background: url(http://extremje.beget.tech/assets/img/index/top.png);
  color: #007fd5
 }
}
@-webkit-keyframes moon {
 0%{
  transform: translate(0, 0);
 }
 100% {
  transform: translate(0,-1000%);
 }
}
@-webkit-keyframes cloud_one {
 /*0% {
  left: 0
 }
 100% {
  left: -200%
 }*/
 0%{
  transform: translate(0, 0);
 }
 100% {
  transform: translate(0,-1000%);
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cloud_two {
 0%{
  transform: translate(0, 0);
 }
 100% {
  transform: translate(0,-1000%);
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cloud_three {
 0%{
  transform: translate(0, 0);
 }
 100% {
  transform: translate(0,-1000%);
 }
}
```

```html
  <header class="paralax">
  <div class="sky" style="http://extremje.beget.tech/assets/img/index/top.png);">
      <div class="moon"></div>
      <div class="clouds_one"></div>
      <div class="clouds_two"></div>
      <div class="clouds_three"></div>
  </div>
 
</header>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите весь необходимый код для воспроизведения проблемы прямо в вопросе. Не стоит добавлять в вопрос ссылки на сторонние сайты.

Comment: вставил  код в вопрос